# Is there a way to retrieve the keys of a hashmap in R?

Tags: r, hashmap

I am new to Hashing algorithms in R

I have a hashmap in R as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
HH <- hashmap(LETTERS, rnorm(26))
```

I am trying to obtain the key for a particular value. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `HH$keys()[HH$values() == x]` for a particular value `x`?

Answer (score 3):

R has a native hash table implementation with performance comparable to other package-based approaches (see https://blog.dominodatalab.com/a-quick-benchmark-of-hashtable-implementations-in-r/ for comparison).

Here is your example,

```
set.seed( 123 );
#' create hash table
HH <- new.env( hash = TRUE );

#' assign() for setting each key value pair (one key:value pair at a time, hence mapply())
mapply(FUN = function(key,value){ assign(key, value, env = HH) }, LETTERS, rnorm(26));

#' given a key, get() returns a single value
get( "A", env = HH );

#' given a vector of keys, mget() returns a list of values
mget( c("B", "C", "D"), env = HH );

#' exists() is handy for querying a hash table for pre-existing key:value pairs
if(!exists("AA", env = HH)){
  assign("AA", runif(1), env = HH)
}
```